# How to share same image on messenger and facebook via meta tags Angular?

Tags: facebook, meta-tags, meta, facebook-messenger, angular-universal

I am dealing with problem of sharing same image on messenger and facebook in Angular PWA app. Whole thing is done using  tags in html. The problem is in size of image, the photo is in recommended size for Facebook 1200x630px and it shows correct. While i am sharing it via messenger it is cut, maybe there should be another image or I didnt configure it correctly. I also set width and height of image using meta. 
Here's code:

```
  <meta property="og:title" th:content="${title}">
  <meta property="og:url" th:content="${url}" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="here is site name" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="here is photo url" />
  <meta property="og:image:width" content="600" />
  <meta property="og:image:height" content="314" />
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="here is facebook app id" />
```

I have a component with shared buttons and messenger is using function from FB docs.

```
shareOnMessenger() {
window.open('fb-messenger://share?link=' + encodeURIComponent(this.detailedViewURL) + '&app_id=' + encodeURIComponent(this.facebookMetaTag.content));
```

}

Comment: _“the photo is in recommended size for Facebook 1200x630px”_ - so your `og:image:width` and `og:image:height` tags _lie_ about that then? Why?

Comment: the physical photo size is 1200x630px, I set sizes in meta tags in order to try if it affects on UI of photo in messenger

Comment: That’s not how that works to begin with. These tags are to tell Facebook what actual size of image to expect, before the image was downloaded for the first time. The values need to match your actual image, this is _not_ a way to apply any “dynamic resizing.” // You can specify more than one `og:image`, so maybe try to add a second size, and see if messenger picks the one you want then. (Don’t forget to purge Facebook’s cache.) Not sure if a recommended aspect ratio or size is documented anywhere, try to match the aspect ratio of what you currently get shown as the “cut” result.

Comment: I found that sizes are mentioned here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/images/

Comment: Yes, but those are the recommendations for sharing on Facebook, there is nothing Messenger-specific in there.